# Remember the Milk desktop alternative

Tags: windows-7, accounting, organizer-software

I am looking for a simple software to track monthly expenses, jobs, etc which is as simple to use as Remember the Milk.

I would like it to be offline, hence a desktop software. My operating system is Windows 7

Comment: Any problem with [syncing RTM and Outlook](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/forums/tips/3269/)?

Comment: needed something that's completely offline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MyLifeOrganized](http://www.mylifeorganized.net/) seems to be the answer to my prayer. TimeEdition is nice but not that comprehensive in features as this one. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [timeEdition time tracker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/timeedition/).

A discussion of it can be found in :
[TimeEdition – An Excellent Yet Simple FOSS Time-Tracker](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/timeedition-excellent-simple-foss-timetracker-crossplatform/)

> An open-source, cross-platform time
>   tracker that requires no installation.
>
> With TimeEdition, you don’t just track
>   time for an activity. You log
>   customers, projects and tasks, so in
>   other words, to track any task, you’ll
>   have to create a new customer first,
>   then a project, then a task, which you
>   can do by heading into the drop-down
>   menu for each field in the main
>   window, or selecting the appropriate
>   entry under View in the menu bar.

Other free option is [Rachota Timetracker](http://rachota.sourceforge.net/en/index.html).